# In GCP, what is the difference between SSH'ing into a VM and using Cloud Shell?

Tags: shell, ssh, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to learn ML on GCP. Some of the Qwiklabs and Tutorials start with Cloud Shell to setup things like env variables and install Python packages, while others start by opening an SSH terminal into a VM to do those preliminary steps.

I can't really tell the difference between the two approaches, other than the fact that in the second case a VM needs to be provisioned first. Presumably, when you use Cloud Shell some sort of VM instance is being provisioned for you behind the scenes anyway.

So how are the two approaches different?

Comment: @robsiemb answer is very good. To add, if you are just getting started in Google Cloud (GCP), start with CloudShell. This is an excellent environment for working with Google Cloud and you don't need to learn how to set up your own system with credentials, tools, etc. Qwiklabs, which is another great resource, uses Cloud Shell so that you do not need to mess up your own system to practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Shell is a product that is designed to give a large number of preconfigured tools that are kept updated, as well as being quick to start, accessable from the UI, and free.  Basically, its a quick way to get an interactive shell.  You can learn more about this environment from [its documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/).

There are also [limits](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations) to Cloud Shell -- you can only use it for 60 hours a week, if you go idle your session is terminated, and there is only 5GB of storage.  It is also only an f1-micro instance, IIRC.  So while it is provisioned for you (and free!), it isn't really useful for anything other than an interactive shell.

On the other hand, SSHing into a VM places you directly in a terminal on that VM, much like you would on any specific host -- you only have whatever tools that the image installed onto that VM provides (and many VMs come pretty bare bones, it depends on the image).  But, you're now in a terminal on the host that is likely executing the code you want to work with, and it has as much CPU and RAM as you provisioned in that instance.

As far as guides pointing you to one or the other -- thats really up to them, but I suspect they'd point client / tool type work to the cloud shell (since its easy and a reasonably standard environment, which can even be [scripted with tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/walkthroughs)), while they'd probably point how to install necessary software for use in production to a "real" VM.